# Pandas assign a value to a cell, why does this not work?

Tags: python, pandas

If I initialize a new column to zeros:

```
df['key'] = 0
```

then:

```
df.loc[0]['key']
Out[538]: 0
```

but when I set it to a new value:

```
df.loc[0]['key'] = 1
```

Calling that entry still returns zero...

```
df.loc[0]['key']
Out[538]: 0
```

What is going on?

Comment: df.loc[0,'key']=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`df.loc[0]['key']` is a slice of `df.loc[0]`, so you're setting a value on a slice, not the dataframe itself. Conversely `.loc` and `.iloc` refer back to the dataframe itself, so you should be able to update the original value if you call `df.loc[0, 'key']=1`.